# PHP 5.4.9 Mysqli issue

Tags: php, server-setup, extension

On Ubuntu 12.04 server I had PHP 5.4.9 installed from the source:

> ./configure --prefix=/etc/php --with-apxs2=/etc/apache2/bin/apxs --with-config-file-path=/etc/php --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php/conf.d --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/libxml2 --with-xsl=/usr/local/libxslt --with-mysql --with-zlib --with-pdo-mysql --enable-calendar --with-gd --with-iconv-dir --enable-mbstring --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-zip --with-curl --with-openssl --with-kerberos --with-tidy'

Then, using apt-get, I had mysql server and phpMyAdmin installed. Unfortunatelly phpMyAdmin keep saying that 'mysqli' and 'mcrypt' not installed. *php -m | grep mysqli* just confirms it.

So I tried to install mysqli with "apt-get install php5-mysqli", but just got message to do it by means of "php5-mysqlnd" or "php5-mysql". Even though they are already installed (according to phpinfo()) I tried - doesn't work. However, in php.ini, there's mysqli staff like "extension=php_mysqli.dll", but no "extension=mysqli.so". And block [MySQLi] with some uncommented settings also present.

Since this is my first attempt to build php from source I reckon I did some silly mistake.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPD: PROBLEM SOLVED
1. To enable mcrypt extension (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/) 
1.1 download, unpack, config, compile and install **Libmcrypt** library

> wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mcrypt/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz
>   tar xf libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz
>   cd libmcrypt-2.5.8
>   ./configure
>   make && make install

1.2 download, unpack, config (I added desirable path: ----prefix=/usr/local/mcrypt), compile and install **mcrypt**

> wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mcrypt/MCrypt/2.6.8/mcrypt-2.6.8.tar.gz
>   tar xf lmcrypt-2.6.8.tar.gz
>   cd lmcrypt-2.6.8
>   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mcrypt
>   make && make install

2.to install mysqli I followed proposed options of configuring php taken from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

> ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql_config  \
>   --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
>   --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
>   [other options]

So after installing Libmcrypt, mcrypt in /usr/local/mcrypt and adding changes to configuration of php I had finally succeeded. The final config looks this way:

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/php --with-apxs2=/etc/apache2/bin/apxs --with-config-file-path=/etc/php --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php/conf.d --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/libxml2 --with-xsl=/usr/local/libxslt --with-mysql --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/mcrypt --with-zlib --enable-calendar --with-gd --with-iconv-dir --enable-mbstring --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-zip --with-curl --with-openssl --with-kerberos --with-tidy --with-pcre-regex
```

P.S: Note that to run this you would need download, config, compile and install libxml, libxslt, prce, mcrypt, Libmcrypt

Comment: If you've resolved your problem, please accept the answer that solved your problem (or post your own answer, if the solution was different, and accept it). This way others know that the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you need PHP with mcrypt and mysql support, where are --with-mcrypt --with-mysqli options?

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment (which I've deleted, but I know it still shows up in your feed) as I made a mistake